# Best practices for using EC2 to host java web services

Tags: java, android, web-services, amazon-web-services

I'm in the middle of writing an android app, and i'd like to externalise some of the features into an external service.
I could either use my existing hosting, and write some simple php web services, or do something a little more involved- (which would have th advantage of me not having to learn php). 
Ideally, I'd like to write my web services in java because I'm already comfortable with writing and securing them. 
I'm wondering whether this is a sensible use of Ec2, and if so, which AMI would be the best to use?

any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking at a java web service and you'd like it to scale well AWS's Elastic Beanstalk is Amazon's turnkey solution.  It takes care of automatically scaling your app as demand grows and shrinks.

http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/